# LastInsertId is returning 0, when using database/sql package with oracle driver

Tags: oracle, go, last-insert-id, lastinsertid

I am using database/sql package with oracle driver (“gopkg.in/rana/ora.v4”), when I am inserting the data, it’s LastInsertId Method is returning 0, while data is successfully inserted.
Attaching code.

```
package main

import (
    “database/sql”
    “fmt”

    _ "gopkg.in/rana/ora.v4"
)

func main() {
    conn, err = sql.Open(“ora”, 
    username+"/"+password+"@"+host+":"+port+"/"+sid)
    query := “INSERT INTO Table (C2) VALUES (:C2)”
    result, err := conn.Exec(query, “Test”)
    if err!= nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    lastId := result.LastInsertId() // returning 0
    fmt.Println(lastId)
}
```

Please tell me why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

From [the documentation](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/rana/ora.v4#hdr-LastInsertId) (emphasis added):

> ## LastInsertId
>
> The `database/sql` package provides a LastInsertId method to return the last inserted row's id. **Oracle does not provide such functionality, but if you append `... RETURNING col /*LastInsertId*/` to your SQL, then it will be presented as LastInsertId.** Note that you have to mark with a `/*LastInsertId*/` (case insensitive) your `RETURNING` part, to allow ora to return the last column as `LastInsertId()`. That column must fit in `int64`, though!